# zmq not works in django + apache + mod_wsgi

Tags: python, django, apache, zeromq

I have deployed a django project in apache with mod_wsgi.so in windows server
( python2.7 32-bit, apache2.2 32-bit, windows server 64-bit ). 
I import zmq, and it works well in django project. But within apache, the whole project crash... If I delete "import zmq", the project can work in apache.
It seems that there is something wrong between mode_wsgi and zmq.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this bug.
Firstly I traced the error in apache's error log, and found that it was windows error 126 and in zmq's initialization：**init**.py when loading libsodium

[Thu May 05 20:16:22 2016] [error]     import zmq
[Thu May 05 20:16:22 2016] [error]   File "D:\Program Files\python27\lib\site-packages\zmq\__init__.py", line 42, in 
[Thu May 05 20:16:22 2016] [error]     _libsodium = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(bundled_sodium[0])
[Thu May 05 20:16:22 2016] [error]   File "D:\Program Files\python27\Lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 443, in LoadLibrary
[Thu May 05 20:16:22 2016] [error]     return self._dlltype(name)
[Thu May 05 20:16:22 2016] [error]   File "D:\Program Files\python27\Lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 365, in **init**
[Thu May 05 20:16:22 2016] [error]     self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
[Thu May 05 20:16:22 2016] [error] WindowsError: [Error 126]

so I add

```js
from . import libsodium, libzmq
```

to **init**.py, and it works well